# how to create magic square in java?

Tags: java

my task is to write a program that ask user for an input and the method will return whether or not the input forms a magic square. No matter what I enter into the console, the program returns that I entered a magic square. What am I missing?

Magic square definition: a 2 dimensional array is a magic square if the sum of the rows, columns, and diagonals is the same.

```
here is the Code:


    public class MagicSquares {


public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int current = 0;
    do{
        System.out.print("Enter an int. Enter -1 when done>");
        current = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());
    }while(current != -1);
    int numInputs = ints.size();
    int square = (int) Math.sqrt(numInputs);

    if(square*square == numInputs){
        int[][] intSquare = new int[square][square];
        int x = 0;
        while(x < numInputs){
            for(int y = 0; y < square; ++y){
                for(int z = 0; z < square; ++z){
                    intSquare[y][z] = ints.get(x);
                    ++x;
                }
            }
        }
        if(isMagicSquare(intSquare)){
            System.out.println("You entered a magic square");
        }else{
            System.out.println("You did not enter a magic square");
        }

    }else{
        System.out.println("You did not enter a magic square. " +
                "You did not even enter a square...");
    }
}


private static Boolean isMagicSquare(int[][] array){
    int side = array.length;
    int magicNum = 0;
    for(int x = 0; x < side; ++x){
        magicNum =+ array[0][x];
    }
    int sumX = 0;
    int sumY = 0;
    int sumD = 0;
    for(int x = 0; x > side; ++x){
        for (int y = 0; y < side; ++y){
            sumX =+ array[x][y];
            sumY =+ array[y][x];
        }
        sumD =+ array[x][x];
        if(sumX != magicNum  || sumY != magicNum || sumD != magicNum){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}



}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You didn't save what is entered, so 0x0 square is passed to `isMagicSquare()`.
- The implementation of `isMagicSquare()` is wrong in many points.

  - The condition `x > side` should be `x < side`.
  - You have to check `sumD` only after is calculation is finished.
  - You have to initialize `sumX` and `sumY` before calculating them.
  - You should use `+=` instead of `=+` to calculate the sum.

To correct:

Make the code save the input

```
do{
    System.out.print("Enter an int. Enter -1 when done>");
    current = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());
    if (current != -1) ints.add(current); // add this line to the loop to read the input
}while(current != -1);
```

and correct `isMagicSquare()`.

```
private static Boolean isMagicSquare(int[][] array){
    int side = array.length;
    int magicNum = 0;
    for(int x = 0; x < side; ++x){
        magicNum += array[0][x];
    }
    int sumD = 0;
    for(int x = 0; x < side; ++x){
        int sumX = 0;
        int sumY = 0;
        for (int y = 0; y < side; ++y){
            sumX += array[x][y];
            sumY += array[y][x];
        }
        sumD =+ array[x][x];
        if(sumX != magicNum  || sumY != magicNum){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return sumD == magicNum;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your outer loop in `isMagicSquare` is never entered, so you always return true.

Change

```
for(int x = 0; x > side; ++x)
```

to

```
for(int x = 0; x < side; ++x)
```

Beside that, `sumD != magicNum` should only be tested outside the outer loop, otherwise your method will return false in cases that should return true. And `sumX` and `sumY` should be reset in each iteration of the outer loop.

Therefore `isMagicSquare()` should look like this :

```
private static Boolean isMagicSquare(int[][] array){
    int side = array.length;
    int magicNum = 0;
    for(int x = 0; x < side; ++x){
        magicNum += array[0][x];
    }
    int sumD = 0;
    for(int x = 0; x < side; ++x){
        int sumX = 0;
        int sumY = 0;
        for (int y = 0; y < side; ++y){
            sumX += array[x][y];
            sumY += array[y][x];
        }
        sumD += array[x][x];
        if(sumX != magicNum  || sumY != magicNum){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return sumD == magicNum;
}
```

In addition, you forgot to add the inputs to `ints` :

```
do{
    System.out.print("Enter an int. Enter -1 when done>");
    current = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());
    if (current != -1) ints.add(current); // add this
}while(current != -1);
```